# using python libraries downloaded from external sources

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu

I've downloaded python libraries (tar.gz) from external links. How to use these libraries, I mean in which directory under the python should I unzip such libraries.

How to use downloaded libraries with python when we are using:

1. windows 7
2. Ubuntu

Also how to install these libraries without using *pip* in Linux? Do we have to set path in windows7 to use the libraries?

**Guys better to post comments then to give negative points. With your suggestion I can modify my post. I dont think you to be smart guy by rating negative points in any comments.**

Comment: You extract them wherever you want and run `python setup.py install` on that directory.

Comment: Thanks parchment for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux based systems (e.g., Ubuntu):

```
$ tar xzf package.tar.gz
$ cd package
$ python setup.py install
```

Also, look input `pip` https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip

Answer (score 0):

On Windows and Linux, all you need to do is unzip the archive somewhere, cd into and run the following command as administrator (usually by running cmd.exe as Administrator on Windows or by using `sudo` on Linux):

```
python setup.py install
```

If the package does not have a setup.py, it can get tricky. Most of the time the package just needs to be copied into your Python's `site-packages` folder.

You will find some packages that need to be built. On Linux, you can usually do this pretty easily. On Windows, you will need the appropriate compiler, usually a free version of Visual Studio will do, although you have to make sure you get the correct version of Visual Studio. I've heard reports that you can also use MingW.